# What is the difference between regular and console specific SSDs

Tags: ssd

That said, I'm looking to get a new M2 SSD for my computer, and perusing the web I found that I can by a 2 TB drive for about $120, while I can buy a [redacted console name] SSD of the same capacity, and pay about $40 more for the privilege. Both of these are Western Digital Black 850 drives, so this should be a legitimate “apples to apples” comparison.

What exactly is the difference between these two devices to warrant such a large price difference, and if the console version is in fact better, would it be worth getting one for a desktop computer?

Comment: The only reference I see for console SSD is gaming consoles.  1 TB Samsung SSDs with 600 TBW capacity are more more expensive that what you are suggesting above. Make sure you are getting a good lifetime spec (TBW) with your selection.

Comment: I wouldn't imagine there is any functional difference between those two product lines other than a premium for one of them.  Now there might be specific speed compatibility concerns.

Comment: it also may be based on whether there is a preformatted volume on them. I'd not expect to run a partition editor on an xbox. makes me think of the old 3.5" apple vs IBM formatted DSDD you;d buy a box of. for some reason that used to make a difference in the long-long-ago

Comment: @FrankThomas From experience I am sure that the "console" in question is the PS5, which is capable of using a standard NVMe SSD so long as it is capable of over 5GB/s transfer speeds. When inserted the PS5 will initialise and format the disk as required, there is no requirement for the manufacturer to do it. The Xbox, by contrast, uses a custom [weird little "memory stick" style SSD](https://www.xbox.com/en-GB/accessories/hard-drives/seagate-expansion-card) by Seagate which *might* need formatting but it cannot natively be used in a PC without some kind of adaptor, though it may still be NVMe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playstation 5 SSDs absolutely require a heatsink due to poor airflow, and that heatsink absolutely cannot be larger than a particular size due to height restrictions.

In a PC that same SSD might not require a heatsink as there is good airflow. Also many newer motherboard have heatsink covers for NVMe SSDs and so don't need a heatsink on the SSD itself.

The result is that you pay a premium for an SSD with a heatsink guaranteed to both fit and be good enough for use in a PS5.  When the PS5 was first enabled to allow NVMe SSDs there was a good market for "standard" high end SSDs and low profile heatsinks from third parties.

There is no difference between the SSDs. The only difference is having a pre-fitted heatsink that is known good for the console.